# iterate through filename and merge according to pattern, BASH

Tags: bash

I have 100s of files in pairs with similar name pattern: which means, their file names are "A0-B1.fastq.0.1.82.fastq" & "A0-B2.fastq.0.1.82.fastq", where B0 and B1 indicate two different pairs. "82" in the file names stands for random number. The directory have files with random number ranging from 82 to 100. Thus, for every random number, there are two pair of files (A0-B1 and A0-B2).
I want to merge both pairs for each random numbers.

Here is what I tried:

```
INPUT=`ls A0-*.0.1.*.fastq`

#set values for pair and random
p=`seq 1 1 2`
r=`seq 82 2 100`

for r in $INPUT;
do
cat A0-${p}.fastq.0.1.${r}.fastq > A0.merged.${r}.fastq
done
```

What am I missing to get the correct output ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this script -

```
for i in {82..100..2}
do
    if ls A0-*.fastq.0.1.${i}.fastq 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then
        cat A0-*.fastq.0.1.${i}.fastq > A0.merged.${i}.fastq
    fi
done
```

Comment: @anishsane Except there is a glob, in which case `test -f` might fail if multiply path names are expanded. Try `test -f *`

Comment: OK... actually, looking at OP's script, I thought OP has fixed file names with $p taking values 1 & 2. So glob would not be needed. But you are right, `-f` will fail, if used for glob.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you :

```
for r in {82..100}; do
  if [[ -f A0-B1.fastq.0.1.${r}.fastq ]] && [[ -f A0-B2.fastq.0.1.${r}.fastq ]]; then
    cat A0-B1.fastq.O.1.${r}.fastq A0-B2.fastq.O.1.${r}.fastq > A0.merged.${r}.fastq
  fi
done
```